# Tango 3d scanner quality is poor. Could somebody help me how to improve it?

Tags: google-project-tango

[I have tried same demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDjU2.jpg) from the official repo for 3d scanning and i get really poor quality of 3d environment. I have tried change values of tango manager prefab and other settings but still its same.

I have a screenshot:

[image: ExperimentalMeshBuilderWithColo demo].

Answer (score 1):

The mesh generated by the tango sdk is optimized for performance regarding memory and reconstruction speed, it is perfect for physics and occlusion but if you want to reconstruct high quality meshes I would recommend to use different reconstruction pipelines.

Comment: To add on this answer a little bit more, to see the raw data from the depth sensor, you can try the point cloud example.